# Output a specific result from array of objects aggregation - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have a data looking like this:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("620ca4e292a990273446cf7b"),
  "data": [
    {
      "flagging": "BUSINESS",
      "information": [
        {
          "room": 1,
          "status": "AVAILABLE"
        },
        {
          "room": 2,
          "status": "BUSY"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "flagging": "PRIVATE",
      "information": [
        {
          "room": 1,
          "status": "AVAILABLE"
        },
        {
          "room": 2,
          "status": "CLEANING"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "flagging": "PUBLIC",
      "information": [
        {
          "room": 1,
          "status": "SERVICE"
        },
        {
          "room": 2,
          "status": "AVAILABLE"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": "2022-02-16T07:16:50.674Z"
}
```

I'm trying to make a service whether user can input a certain flagging, and the data with the corresponding flagging will show as a result. I tried using this code below but what I get are all the datas, not the filtered ones.

```
db.coll.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { _id: ObjectId("620ca4e292a990273446cf7b") },
    },
    {
        $project: { _id: 0, "data": 1 }
    }
])
```

What should I change in the code so I can get the following result (if the requested flagging are BUSINESS and PUBLIC)?

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "flagging": "BUSINESS",
      "information": [
        {
          "room": 1,
          "status": "AVAILABLE"
        },
        {
          "room": 2,
          "status": "BUSY"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "flagging": "PUBLIC",
      "information": [
        {
          "room": 1,
          "status": "SERVICE"
        },
        {
          "room": 2,
          "status": "AVAILABLE"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need  [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) in the `$project` stage  to filter the nested document(s) in `data` array with `flagging` is within `["BUSINESS", "PUBLIC"]`.

```
{
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    data: {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$data",
        "cond": {
          $in: [
            "$$this.flagging",
            [
              "BUSINESS",
              "PUBLIC"
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vnoLH8-hXXz)

Comment: This certainly works, thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to see it helped. =)